# Customize Drupal 6 Nice_Menus Output

Tags: routes

I had asked this exact question on StackOverflow, until I cam across this StackExchange site...makes much more sense to post this here!

I'm using **nice_menus-6.x-2.1** with Drupal 6.22 and would like to know if there is any way to rewrite the menu output so that the end-result resembles the following:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="node/xx">Parent Link 1</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="node/xx">Parent Link 2</a>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="node/xx">Child Link 2<span>[Description]</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="node/xx">Child Link 2<span>[Description]</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="node/xx">Parent Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Basically, I only want the customization on the second tier of sub-menus onwards. The `<div>` wrapper is there for styling purposes. The `<span>` within the link tag is supposed be the description that you usually get on mouse-over, but I want this to show a bit smaller below the link (but be part of the link itself, and therefore not outside the `<a>` tag).
I'm sure this is possible? I just don't know where to start.  I'm looking within **nice_menus.module** but can't seem to find the function for the children rewrite. I currently have this working in a mock using plain HTML markup and CSS, but I just can't work out how to customize the PHP function in Drupal.

Has anyone been through this and would care to share?

Thanks a million everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you would just want to implement your own version of theme_nice_menus_build(), and add all your required divs/spans right there.

Comment: ok, thanks Maciej! How do I go about doing that?  Sorry, I'm newish to Drupal...but going thru all the reading material I can to understand the core system better.

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/341628

Comment: thanks, I'll post back here if the article contains what I'm looking for

Comment: thanks Maciej, the links toward the bottom seem to point me right direction.