# Suggestion tpl help for NiceMenu markup?

Tags: 7, routes, blocks, theming

I'm using NiceMenus to display my taxonomy tree. Since I chose no parent menu, the module displays the root items as separate hoverable menu "tiles", which is OK. They are however `<li>` items enclosed in one `<ul>`. Due to styling/layout issues, what I want is that each of the tiles have individual parent `<ul>`.

So instead of having:

```
<ul>
 <li>root item 1</li> 
 <li>root item 2</li>
 <li>root item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want:

```
<ul>
 <li>root item 1</li> 
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>root item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>root item 3</li>
</ul>
```

and then I'll be able to easily absolutely position each `<ul>`.

So the question is presumably a piece of cake for you guys: how to change the markup - probably using a suggestion technique... Should I override the block? How should I name the tpl file so to force my markup?

Thanks,
Artur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you just position your li's absolutely? Generally, you should be able to position li's the same way as separate ul's using CSS.

Anyway though, to answer your question, have a look here: [Customize Drupal 6 Nice_Menus Output](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6071/customize-drupal-6-nice-menus-output/6079#6079)

(Ok, you're asking for D7, but the general idea should be the same/very similar.)

Comment: I'm just in the process of inspecting the available variables to see if I can tailor the code to my needs. If not, I will probably position the ul and li absolutely as one block. Which stinks a bit, but well... Dzięki enyłej ;-)